# ¿Utilizaremos el mismo logo que StackOverflow?

Tags: discusión

Eso. Me encantaría ver alguna propuesta de *españolización* del logo de StackOverflow, aunque como está ahora a mi me parece bastante bien, supongo que tenemos el chance, como comunidad, de elegir algo diferente.

Comment: si a logo te refieres a el que se muestra cuando abres el tour por ejemplo o al que muestra el navegador en la pestaña, ami me gusta ese, ja, pero no digo que otro también no quedase bien, pero en general el logo de SO mola, Saludos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No podremos editar o cambiar el logo de nuestro sitio.  Como se ha notado, todos los sitios internacionales llevan el mismo logo de SO con subtítulos con el lenguaje apropiado.

Lo que se puede cambiar es el color de fondo.  Actualmente, estos son los colores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

[El sitio en portugués](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) y [el sitio en japonés](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) tienen el mismo logo que el sitio principal, así que supongo que para el sitio en español se hará lo mismo.

(Curiosamente, el subtítulo del sitio en japonés no es "en japonés", sino la transcripción a caracteres katakana de "Stack Overflow")

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al logotipo no creo que cambie más que de color, actualmente es de color amarillo, el logotipo de [StackOverflow en portugues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) por ejemplo tiene un color verde.

En cuanto al nombre como es un nombre propio el cual ya identificamos, podría ser buena idea el cambio del logotipo pero la pregunta sería que podría identificar a únicamente el español. Usuarios de España desearían incorporar un toro al logotipo, usuarios de Perú el Machu Picchu, etc., sin embargo sería interesante tener una "españolización", un logotipo diferente!.

Comment: Eso de que los usuarios de España querrían incorporar un toro es bastante relativo.  El toro es un símbolo con *mucha* polémica en general, por lo que representa.

Comment: Bueno Darkhogg es solo un ejemplo, en realidad es relativo a la idiosincrasia de cada país.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a la palabra stackoverflow del logo pues definitivamente no debe modificarse (seguro que tampoco nos dejarían).

**stackoverflow** es un [nombre propio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_propio) no es una palabra que pueda o deba ser traducida.

Además el logo claramente refleja que es la versión en español de stackoverflow por lo que yo veo que esta muy bien como está.

Por ejemplo esto mismo ocurre con stackoverflow en portugués https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Me refiero al logo como un todo. Cómo ya he dicho, a mi me parece bastante bien como aparece en Beta. Por otro lado, entiendo que es la comunidad la que tiene el chance de definir el logo que quiere utilizar (aunque entiendo que StackOverflow como marca es muy reconocido y que es.StackOverflow es parte de dicha marca), justamente la idea es abrir el debate y dar opción, si alguien la tiene, de hacer propuestas.